# The Sum of Independent Poisson Random Variables is Poisson: Converse

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

Suppose we have random variables $X \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda)$ and $Y \sim \text{Poisson}(\mu)$ such that $X+ Y \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda + \mu)$. Must $X$ and $Y$ be independent?

Contrasting with the analogous case with normal random variables (where the variances sum up correctly), this is true as long as $X$ and $Y$ are jointly normal. Moreover, a covariance calculation shows that $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated, so it would be sufficient to show that uncorrelated Poisson random variables are independent.

Comment: The first paragraph of [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3212423) suggests that there is a 1973 paper by Serfling that shows that the answer is no (but I don't know which paper, since I don't have access to Jstor).

Comment: I think I have an easy "no" example...

Comment: the paper of Serfling referred to is called [Construction of Dependent Uncorrelated Random Variables with Prescribed Marginal Distributions](https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/citations/AD0767014), a university technical report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way of changing 6 $(x,y)$ locations in a grid without affecting any row, column, or top-left-to-bottom-right diagonal:

Define the grid $G=\{(x,y): x,y \in \{0,1,2,...\}\}$. Let $p(x,y)$ be a PMF defined on all $(x,y)\in G$ such that $p(x,y)>0$ for all $(x,y)\in G$. This includes the joint PMF $p(x,y) = \frac{\lambda^x\mu^y}{x!y!}e^{-\lambda}e^{-\mu}$ for two independent Poisson random variables with parameters $\lambda>0, \mu>0$. We want to change $p(x,y)$ to a new PMF $\tilde{p}(x,y)$ without changing the row, column, or top-left-to-bottom-right sums.

Fix $\delta>0$ sufficiently small and change exactly 6 of the $p(x,y)$ values:
\begin{array}{ccc}
p(0, 2)-\delta & p(1,2)+\delta & p(2,2) \\
p(0,1)+\delta & p(1,1) & p(2,1)-\delta\\
p(0,0) & p(1,0)-\delta & p(2,0)+\delta
\end{array}

This change preserves the appropriate sums that specify the marginal mass functions for $X, Y$ and $X+Y$:

\begin{align}
&\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} p(i,y) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \tilde{p}(i,y) \quad \forall y \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\}\\
&\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} p(x,i) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \tilde{p}(x,i)\quad \forall x \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\}\\
&\sum_{i=0}^k p(i,k-i) = \sum_{i=0}^k \tilde{p}(i,k-i) \quad \forall k \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\}
\end{align}

Comment: The assumption that $p(x,y)>0$ for all $(x,y)\in G$ is not crucial. This argument only requires $p(1,0)>0, p(2,1)>0, p(0,2)>0$, and we can take $\delta = \min[p(1,0), p(2,1), p(0,2)]$. A different set of 6 points in $G$ could also be used, as long as it has a similar structure.